# Spring Config server serving plain text

Tags: java, spring-cloud

I'm trying to reproduce http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_serving_plain_text serving a logback.xml file.

When I tried `curl -v http://localhost:8888/gateway/default/master/logback.xml` I got a:

> Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
>
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
>
> Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8888 (#0)
>
> GET /gateway/default/master/logback.xml HTTP/1.1
>
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
>
> Host: localhost:8888
>
> Accept: */*
>
> HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
>
> Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
>
> Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>
> X-Application-Context: configserver:8888
>
> Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
>
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> Date: Thu, 17 Mar 2016 17:26:02 GMT
>
> Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
>
> {"timestamp":1458235562683,"status":406,"error":"Not Acceptable","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException","message":"Could not find acceptable representation","path":"/gateway/default/master/logback.xml"}%

I'm using Brixton.M5 and here is the repository structure:

```
 - application.yml
 - gateway.yml
 - auth.yml
 - eureka.yml
 - logback.xml
 - test.json
```

The `curl -v http://localhost:8888/gateway/default/master/test.json` works normally.

Comment: maybe try with '-H "Accept: application/xml"'

Comment: @freakman same error, but thanks

Comment: Can you try with snapshots? I did using https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo/tree/master with http://localhost:8888/gateway/default/master/test.json and http://localhost:8888/gateway/default/master/books.xml and it worked ok.

Comment: @spencergibb with the build.snapshot version of brixton it worked, please post it as an answer and I`ll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Brixton.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` (RC1 will be out later today or tomorrow).

I did it using http://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo/tree/master with http://localhost:8888/gateway/default/master/test.json and http://localhost:8888/gateway/default/master/books.xml and it worked ok.